# How to remove all handlers created before?

Tags: android, notifications, handler

I'm not sure if I'm trying the right thing.

I want to post a notification twice a day, but only if the user has selected this option. So, if the user turns on a checkbox, two delayed handlers will be posted. If the user unchecks the checkbox, both handlers will be cancelled. It works fine, but if the user turns on the checkbox, close the app, open the app and turns off the checkbox, the notification will be posted anyway. I don't have the original instance of the handler object, so I can't cancel it.
So, how could I get the instance of the first handler I created if I close the app and I open it again?

What should I do? Thanks!!

Comment: Wouldn't using AlarmManager be more appropriate?

Comment: Because I read It is not recommended... "Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler."

Comment: there is no such thing like "delayed handlers". what actually do you mean?

Comment: sorry, I mean I created a handler and I use its sendEmptyMessageDelayed() method.

Comment: so check the main Looper instance, if they are different in both cases you cannot remove Messages from the first one, use Looper.myLooper()

Comment: using handler means your app remains opened the whole time. if it is killed, your handler will disappear as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you mentioned you don't want to use the Alarm Manager because it will fire if your app isn't running - I'm assuming here you only want your Handler to fire if your app is running.

You have a few options:

1. Move your Handler out of the Activity/Fragment, as those are destroyed and recreated, which is causing you to lose track of your original Handler. Place the Handler in a persistent object e.g. An [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) sub-class, [a retained Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)), or a custom class instance whose life-cycle is not bound to an Activity or Fragment (e.g. a singleton object). *Your handler will not fire if the app is killed and re-launched as nothing was persisted to disk.*
2. Leave the Handler where it is. In onStop() call handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null). This will stop this instance of the Handler firing in the future. Now of course you need a way of storing the date/time you wanted your handler to fire if the Activity is recreated. Use onSaveInstanceState()/onRestoreInstanceState() to persist the date the Handler is supposed to fire. In onRestoreInstanceState() if you find a saved date, then schedule the handler for that date. *Your handler will not fire if the app is killed and re-launched as nothing was persisted to disk.*
3. Same as above, except save the date/time to [SharedPrefs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) in onPause() rather than using the saved instance state. Retrieve it in onResume() and schedule the handler accordingly. This will mean the date is persisted across app launches. Your handler will *fire* at the correct time if the app is killed and relaunched.

#### Update

Solution #2 and #3 will result in your handler not firing when the app is backgrounded (but still technically running). If you want this behaviour for some reason then use #1. If you need cross-launch persistence then combine it with #3. However, if you do want this behaviour that does seem to be encroaching on AlarmManager territory.

Comment: Okay!! I used the 1+3 option and I got it. I didn´t know how to create a persistent object. Thanks!!